# Can you use Untangle with 1 NIC as an openvpn server?

Tags: router, openvpn

Hi I have an untangle server in my office with 443(web-interface) and 1194(openvpn port) forwarded to this machine.

Can you configure only 1 NIC for untangle and use it as openvpn server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenVPN can be configured to run on any port you like. We use it on port 443, because in many hotels outgoing connections to ports other than 443 and 80 are blocked and our field staff need to be able to connect.

Therefore, as long as you can freely configure the OpenVPN port, this should be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can configure Untangle to just be a OpenVPN server But it is not designed for it and you will have to configure static routes on your normal/Standard GW.

As for the port Untangle has some problems with moving it from UDP 1194.